# React-native: why JS bridge is the performance bottleneck

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

People say we should minimize passing data via JS bridge. I want to know what exactly makes **JS bridge** slow? Serializing & deserializing should be fast, non?

Comment: Where did you hear that passing data should be minimised? A lot of core react-native functionality makes use of the JS bridge, so I would be surprised that it's advised against.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmiXlJ4ZzAo

Answer (score 0):

As mention by Maria, in video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmiXlJ4ZzAo
JSBridge is slow when exchanging data by serializing and deserializing in high frequency, which can be avoid using pure native way or animated.value way of optimizing

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32751606)